# AZure azcopy Linux - how to pass variable to azcopy

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

Good day

I want to pass the value of $mm to this azcopy. However, since azcopy parameters are in double quotes, it does not want to process correctly.

```
 $mm=04 ; start=`echo "START DATE: $(date)"` ; azcopy cp "https://reco.blob.core.windows.net/raw-voi-2022/2022-$mm/*?sv=2020-0RgUNH8A%3D" "https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/bin-voi-2022/2022-$mm?sv=2021-0HGICxvaLULI%3D"
```

Results:

```
Job 24fa36ea-8bda-cc4f-632a-07db4d922036 has started
Log file is located at: /log/azcopy/24fa36ea-8bda-cc4f-632a-07db4d922036.log

100.0 %, 0 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Skipped, 0 Total,

                                                                                                                                                                                          Job 24fa36ea-8bda-cc4f-632a-07db4d922036 summary                                                                                                                                          Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0333
Number of File Transfers: 0
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Number of Symlink Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 0
Number of File Transfers Completed: 0
Number of Folder Transfers Completed: 0
Number of File Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Folder Transfers Failed: 0
Number of File Transfers Skipped: 0
Number of Folder Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 0
Final Job Status: Completed
```

Thank you.

Comment: instead of declaring the variable $mm=04, Can you try declaring it as mm=04; and call as $mm in you azcopy cmdlet

Comment: Oh... silly me. I forgot I am in Linux. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have summarized our discussion and posting the above comment as an answer.

Since you are running the above cmdlet in Linux, you need to initialize the variable with as `mm=04` instead of using `$mm=04`

Answer (score 0):

When you are in a Linux os, don't use $ to declare a variable.

```
# mm=10 ; start=`echo "START DATE: $(date)"` ; azcopy --overwrite=false cp "https://reco.blob.core.windows.net/raw-scr-2022/2022-$mm/*?sv=2021-11gLGKAJj3mMT8%3D" "https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/bin-scr-2022/2022-$mm?sv=2021-10sDQ%3D" ; end=`echo "END DATE: $(date)"`;  echo $start ; echo $end
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Failed to create one or more destination container(s). Your transfers may still succeed if the container already exists.
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

Job 5b0aa50e-d718-0142-72da-7be5962e3a5f has started
Log file is located at: /log/azcopy/5b0aa50e-d718-0142-72da-7be5962e3a5f.log

49.2 %, 60467 Done, 656 Failed, 58877 Pending, 0 Skipped, 120000 Total (scanning...), 2-sec Throughput (Mb/s): 57442.6611 (Service may be limiting speed)
```